# Including generated files in Makefile dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a set of files that get generated.

```
GENERATED = log/loga.c log/logb.h include/loga.h
```

My target below `initproc` depends on `GENERATED` above. But I can't included `$(GENERATED)` below like `$(INIT_OBJS)`. It says

`fatal error: include/loga.h: No such file or directory` when I do `make initproc`

```
initproc: $(INIT_OBJS) log/loga.o init/initb.o settings/settingc.o
             $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)  $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBSXX)  -o $@
```

How do I include the dependency above ?

Comment: Post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you've shown the link rule, but the error clearly refers to a compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `$(GENERATED)` target with some rules to explain how to generate this files. Moreover you have to manage header, source and object files by using some [`patsusbt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) and [`filter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) functions. Something like that should be working:

```makefile
# All the generated files (source and header files)
GENERATED := log/loga.c log/logb.h include/loga.h

# The rules to generate this files
$(GENERATED):
        <some commands to generate the files ...>

# The rules to generate object files from the generated source files
# This could be merge with another rule from your Makefile
GENERATED_SRC := $(filter %.c,$(GENERATED))
GENERATED_OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(GENERATED_SRC))

$(GENERATED_OBJ): $(GENERATED_SRC)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

# The final target depends on the generated object files
initproc: $(INIT_OBJS) <other objects ...> $(GENERATED_OBJ)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBSXX) -o $@
```